# Corona SDK Vector Circles Antialiasing - does it work?

Tags: vector, lua, coronasdk, geometry, antialiasing

I have searched a ton and even upgraded to graphics 2.0 since I read that antialiasing of vector shapes was now working in Corona. That being said, everything is still either pixelated (in the simulator and my phone) or polygonal (on my Nexus 7).

I have antialiasing turned on in the config file, but did not change any of my draw circle code:

config.lua

```
application = {
  content = {
    width = 320,
    height = 480, 
    scale = "letterBox",
    fps = 60,
    antialias = true,
    xalign = "center",
    yalign = "center",

    imageSuffix = {
        ["@2x"] = 2
    }   
  }
}
```

main.lua

```
local function newDot (i,j)
  local newCircle = display.newCircle( i*40-20, -60, 15)
  newCircle:setFillColor( .2, .6, .86 )
  return newDot
end
```

Should this create antialiased circles?

Thanks!

Comment: Hm :\ not sure what I did to get a -1?

Comment: Why do you even want auto alias for a circle? This doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I have a connect the dots game and I'd like smooth edges. Should I be using images instead?

Comment: Autoaliasing should be working by default since it's been in corona since 2010.

Comment: I think Corona took it out for a while: http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/32777-anti-alias-disabled/. But maybe I'm asking the wrong question. The vector circles I'm creating look like decagons :\ Is there a way to make them actual circles? :P

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, Corona removed the anti-alias boolean as you found in your link. Graphics 2.0 definitely does not support it.

I would suggest just using an image like you mentioned since there is no longer a way to make the vectors for a circle look as smooth as you would like them to.